# How far is Hill's sphere applicable? What's the maximum mass?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

Hill's sphere is the assumed sphere that a smaller body -rotating around a bigger one- attracts other objects to rotate around it.

For example, in the case of Earth, the radius of its Hill's sphere is about $1.5$ million km. That means every smaller object in this distance from Earth will rotate it. The Moon is in $384400$ km distance and so fits in Earth's Hill sphere.

Its formula is as follows:

$$r_H=R\sqrt[3]{\frac{m}{3M}}$$ Where $R$ is the distance between the two objects (smaller and bigger); $m$ is the mass of the smaller's body (e.g. the Earth) and $M$ is the bigger body's mass (e.g. the Sun). so $r_H$ is the Earth's Hill sphere.

But the problem is when we want to find the Sun's Hill sphere. We should put the information of the Sun and the black hole of the Milky Way galaxy in the formula (Sun rotates around the galaxy's center). If we want to find the Earth's radius in this way we get into trouble too!

The obtained Hill sphere for the Sun will be about $112$ light years! But sure no objects rotate around the Sun in this distance!

So we can say the Hill's sphere is applicable just in a limited distance.

Also, what's the maximum mass of the body that can rotate around a bigger body?

Answer (score 2):

The Sun is 1,600,000,000 AU from the galactic center and orbits every 230,000,000 years. The mass of the central body goes as the cube of the distance and inversely with the square of the period. So the gravitational field that the Sun sees appears to come from the galactic center where there is an equivalent mass of

$1,600,000,000^3/230,000,000^2 = 77,000,000,000$ solar masses

Plugging this in to the Hill sphere formula, we get

$r_H = 1,600,000,000 (1/3/77,000,000,000)^{1/3} = 260,000$ AU = 4.1 light years

Assuming I've done the calculation correctly, it seems that our neighborhood is too crowded for this calculation to be useful. If the nearest stars were say 40 light-years away, the concept of the Sun's Hill sphere might be valid.  I'm guessing that anything even 1 light year away would have a hard time orbiting given our current neighbors.

PS. I'm worried that although this approach gives the field correctly, it presumably overestimates the field-gradient and it's probably the field gradient that we should be matching

Comment: How can the center of the Milky Way galaxy have a mass of $77,000,000,000$ solar masses? The most massive black hole in the universe, TON $618$, has a mass of about $66,000,000,000$ solar masses. By contrast, Sagittarius A*, the black hole of our own galaxy has just a mass of about $4,300,000$ solar masses.

Comment: @SnackExchange This is not a real mass. It is the ficticious point mass that produces the field required for the Sun to orbit the Milky Way every 230 million years at a distance of 1,600 million AU.  It may bear some relationship to the mass enclosed by the Sun's orbit except that the galaxy has a very non-spherical distribution.

Comment: I think the fact that the Sun's Hill sphere has a radius of about $4.1$ light-years explains why the nearest star to the Sun is about $4.246$ light-years away.

Comment: @SnackExchange That might be a bit of a leap.  But it maybe it's an indicator that we live in a part of the galaxy where the stars are reasonably spaced and it's not too chaotic for life to develop and persist.

Answer (score 1):

The Moon in general moves around the Sun. If you look from outside, you would see a trajectory mostly around the Sun and could deduce there is a disturbance caused by some object (called Earth), the same for the Earth circling around the Galactic center.

Your second point: Objects do in reality not move around another, but they move around their common center of mass. So the rotating mass can be as large, as you wish, and you talk about circling around the Earth since the center of mass of Earth and Moon are inside the Earth.

The Hill radius is just calculated for two masses $m$ and $M$. The Sun around the Galactic center does not fit this simple model.

Answer (score 1):

The Hill-sphere is a concept that exists in the framework of the circularly restricted three-body problem. The solutions of this problem apply when the second body has approx. $<1/27$ of the mass of the central body.

Furthermore there must be only three bodies and their masses must be ordered hierarchically. Galaxies are fundamentally different objects: Most of their mass is distributed in the galactic disc, while the central supermassive black hole does not play a major role in its dynamics. Therefore, the application of $r_{\rm H}$ in a galactic context does not make sense.